# Accepting functions of Any type in scala

Tags: scala

Consider following code:

```
val x: Any = 3 // Int assignable to Any

def k(x:Any){ 3 }
println(k(2)) // Int assignable to Any

def g(h: Any => Any): Unit = h()
def f = (x:Int) => 3
println(g(f))  // type mismatch error: Int => Int not assignable to Any => Any
```

**Questions**:

1. Why is `Int` assignable to `Any`, but `Int => Int` is not?
2. How to make this work? How to declare a function type that accepts and returns any type of value?

**Edit**:

Thanks to GPI, it could be made to work like this:

```
def g = (x:Int) => x*x
def holder[In, Out](f: In => Out, v:In) = { f(v) }
println(holder(g, 3))
```

Comment: `Int => Int` is assignable to `Any` but it's not assignable to `Any => Any`. In your example you're trying to pass `()` to a function with an `Int` parameter.

Comment: Use `Nothing => Any` instead of `Any => Any`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well your assertions are not totally exact.

E.g.a function of type `Int => Int` is indeed an `Any`:

```
scala> val iToi = (input: Int) => input
iToi: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> iToi(3)
res0: Int = 3

scala> val test: Any = iToi
test: Any = <function1>
```

The issue you have is indeed that a `Int => Int` is not a `Any => Any` but this one is easy to understand :

- A `Any => Any` function accepts anything as an argument, for example, a String.
- A `Int => Int` does not accept a String as an argument
- Therefore it should not, and is not, possible to take a `Int => Int` and "cast" it to a `Any => Any`.

The otherway around

- A `Any => Any` returns anyting as a result, it can return a `String` or an `Int`.
- A `Int => Int` returns an Int.
- If we restrict ourselves to a view of the result side of the function, they are compatible.

And indeed, we can say :

```
scala> val test2: Int => Any = iToi
test2: Int => Any = <function1>
```

This works.

One could write a generic function accepting any kind of function this way (but there are many more I'd bet are better, I'm not that good in Scala yet :-) ) :

```
scala> def holder[In, Out](f: In => Out) = { f.toString }
holder: [In, Out](f: In => Out)String

scala> holder(iToi)
res0: String = <function1>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you deal with `T => R` function, in reality you have object of class 
 `Function1[@scala.specialized -T1, @scala.specialized +R]`
 with two class parameters.

First parameter (`T` in our case) is in *contravariant* position (minus in front of T1), so you can not provide sub type when it wants super type.

So either change signature of `f` to `def f = (x:Any) => 3`
or alternatively parameter of `g` to `Int => Any`